# Circle packing representation of a given graph

Tags: geometry, graph-theory, packing-problem

Based on the [Circle packing theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing_theorem): "For every connected simple planar graph G there is a circle packing in the plane whose intersection graph is (isomorphic to) G."

I would like to draw the circle packing representation of this graph (the original graph in the picture).

I am trying using geogebra, but I am new at it and I am not able to get it done. Do you have any suggestion about other software or plug-ins of geogebra that can help.

[image: original]

UPDATE: 19/May/2011 - This one includes the circular packing for the graph (thanks to geogebra user forum - http://www.geogebra.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=21841):

[image]

NOTE:
This question is related to: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/63861/representations-of-regular-maps-four-color-theorem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to post this question to the [GeoGebra user forum](http://www.geogebra.org/forum/viewforum.php?f=2&sid=44023cb008540cbe1b7018a04d2e1674), with a little more info about the obstacles you're running into.

Also, have you ever worked with the [Geometer's Sketchpad](http://www.keypress.com/x24795.xml)?  It's available for a trial, and if you're happy with it, it costs ~$30.00?